# How to call a function, to be executed remotely, using a different function

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

How would I be able to make this script work?

```
function funcOne
{
    $output = <# some script #>
}

function funcTwo
{
    $output = <# some script #>
}

function invokingFunc
{
    param (
      $Function
    )

    Invoke-Command $session ${Function:< funcOne or funcTwo here! >}
}
```

Trying to keep it as simple as possible, as is the PS way, or am I already making this too  complicated for Powershell?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Scriptblock ${Function:funcOne}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it as part of the ScriptBlock. More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

```
function funcOne
{
    "funcOne output"
}
function funcTwo
{
    "funcTwo output"
}
function Invoke-Func
{
    param (
      [scriptblock]$Function,
      [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]$Session
    )

    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $Function
}

Invoke-Func -Session $session -Function ${Function:funcone}
```

When a function is defined, it is accessible through the `Function:` drive. You can access the scriptblock of the function definition in numerous ways. See below for some examples:

```
${Function:FuncOne} # Supports functions with special characters in the name

$Function:FuncOne # Only for functions with simple names, ie no -

(Get-ChildItem Function:\FuncOne).ScriptBlock
```